# '' does not contain a definition for 'LegendName' and no accessible extension method 'LegendName' accepting a first argument of type '' could be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am working on one of my first ASP.net applications and I am having a problem.
On my cshtml razor page, I use an asp-for, but the variable inside the asp-for is not recognized, but I have no idea why it is not recognized.

This is my full error:

'_Views_Home_ApexLegendsTeamBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'LegendName' and no accessible extension method 'LegendName' accepting a first argument of type '_Views_Home_ApexLegendsTeamBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

This is the code from my cshtml page:

```
@page

@{ 
    BllApexLegendsTeamBuilder.CLSBussLayer bussLayer = new BllApexLegendsTeamBuilder.CLSBussLayer();
    var list = bussLayer.GetGebruikers();
}
<div>
    <form method="post">
        <label for="name">Legend Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" asp-for="LegendName"/>
    </form>

</div>
```

And this is the code from my cshtml.cs file:

```
namespace ApexLegendsTeamBuilder.Views.Home
{
    public class ApexLegendsTeamBuilderModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public string LegendName { get; set; }
        [BindProperty]
        public string LegendType { get; set; }
        private readonly ILogger<ApexLegendsTeamBuilderModel> _logger;


        private CLSBussLayer bussLayer { get; set; }
```

I have no clue why it won't recognize the LegendName variable.
I am kinda a c# and asp.net noob so could you explain your answer really simple, so that I can learn.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: nobody ever tries to read an exception messages :( _"'_Views_Home_ApexLegendsTeamBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'LegendName'"_ means that a class named `_Views_Home_ApexLegendsTeamBuilder` has no definition for a property named `LegendName`. If you would read this, you might have noticed that `_Views_Home_ApexLegendsTeamBuilder` is looking a bit different from your `ApexLegendsTeamBuilder.Views.Home.ApexLegendsTeamBuilderModel` class name and this should lead you to the idea that you have forgot to add a `@model` declaration to your page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding:

```
@model ApexLegendsTeamBuilder.Views.Home.ApexLegendsTeamBuilderModel
```

To your `cshtml`  after `@page`. A `@model` directive is used to specify specifying what class is used as the model for the page. You can read more about `PageModel` files [here](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages#pagemodel-files).